# MLPRegressor - Why nobody transfroms the target data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I don't understand why nobody scales the Target data when training a machine learning algorithm such as MLPRegressor (SKLearn)?

I always see something like this:

```
# separate array into input and output components
X = array[:,0:8]
Y = array[:,8]
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X)
StandardX = scaler.transform(X)
```

But would expect something like this:

```
# separate array into input and output components
X = array[:,0:8]
Y = array[:,8]
StandardX = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
Standardy = sc_y.fit_transform(y.values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to scale target variable. There were similar questions here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re

Comment from me: I do it very rare. For example, for visualizing learning curves of complicated and long-learning DNN. Pictures become a bit more beautiful.